# Spring Boot Programmatically setting profiles

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8, spring-profiles

How to set active profile in Spring Boot Application. This application will be deployed in standalone Tomcat.

I have 2 property files `application-{profile}.properties`.

My Application class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
        
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {        
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty(AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, "dev");
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

If I run the app with embedded Tomcat the `dev` profile is  set as active and it works fine. But when I deploy in standalone Tomcat, it does not work.

I tried to set active profile in configure method. but I get `NullPointerException`, when I get the environment from the context.

Any help on how to set the active profile.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I also had the same problem and after struggling for half a day I ended up with this:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.setProperty(AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, "dev");
            SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            System.setProperty(AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, "dev"); 
            super.onStartup(servletContext);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 27):

You can set additional [Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles) on start up:

```java
SpringApplication springApp = new SpringApplication(Main.class);
springApp.setAdditionalProfiles("profile1", "profile2");
springApp.run(args);
```

Comment: This is a better answer - Reason - The Accepted Answer does not take into account of Deployment done on Micro profile Servers. On these , typically many wars are deployed which would share the active.profiles flag. By doing Accepted Answer - we would override the other app flags !

Comment: @user1428716, which is better depends on if you want to replace the active profile or add additional profiles

Comment: This adds additional profiles at the beginning, is there a way to set them at the end? e.g if current profile is set to "profile0", `springApp.setAdditionalProfiles("profile1", "profile2");` would make it as profile1, profile2, profile0.

Answer (score 14):

Another way of doing it in **Spring Boot 2** is by using `SpringApplicationBuilder`:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MySpringProgram.class)
                .profiles("profile1", "profile2")
                .run(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of activating the profile dynamically, you can put the profiles as vm-arguments in the catalina.sh

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"
```

Comment: I have a similar situation. As of now, application-{profile} is created and active profile is set while running the application through --spring.profiles.active=dev. Its working fine. Currently the application is ran from eclipse. If I deploy this to tomcat, how can i achieve this?

Comment: @sunitha you can set the profile in tomcat vm-rguments and it should work

Answer (score 3):

```
System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SpringApplication app =new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAM", "dev");
    app.setDefaultProperties(props);
    app.run(args);
```

I think this code is better solution, because it doesn't set system property

Comment: Generally, Stack Overflow prefers an explanation over "Code only" answers.  Consider adding detail on how this code answers the question.