# springboot app: how to set profile propery with spel?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I try to set active profile as follows:

**Application.properties (inside classpath)**

```
spring.profile.active = ${app.profile}
```

The property "app.profile" comes from Application.properties outside JAR:

**Application.properties file (external)**

```
app.profile = dev
```

Spring refusing to load the "dev" profile. when i set the "spring.profile.active" property inside classpath it work as expected.

There is an alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can specify the profile name while starting the Spring boot app.

**running from CMD**

```
java -jar my-first-spring-boot-app.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

**Running from Eclipse** 
add `spring.profiles.active=dev` as VM argument

Refer the following url if you want to pro-grammatically set profile. 
[Spring Boot Programmatically setting profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267274/spring-boot-programmatically-setting-profiles)

Comment: Is it possible to change the property name?  cause user will edit these external properties

Comment: no property cant change (spring.profiles.active) only the value(dev) is changable

Comment: My goal is that the user will change the "app.profile" property and then spring.profile.active = ${app.profile} will set the right profile.

Comment: all other external properties work as expected, except the profile

Answer (score 0):

You can set the active profile in `web.xml` file of your web application. Please see below code snippet:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
  <param-value>dev, testdb</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If their is no web.xml file and you are configuriong your web application using Java, then you can use `WebApplicationInitializer`. Please see below code snippet:

```
class WebAppInitializer extends WebApplicationInitializer {

  void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("profileName");
      rootContext.register(SpringConfiguration.class);
      container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
  }
}
```

`WebAppInitializer` need to be annotated with `@Configuration` for this to work.

Please let me know if it helps or you need more help.

Comment: i am working on app with REST only. "WebApplicationInitializer" is the right way?

Comment: My goal is that the user will change the "app.profile" property and then spring.profile.active = ${app.profile} will set the right profile.
all other external properties work as expected, except the profile.