# Set active Spring Boot profile for Tomcat Webapp internally (via application.properties)

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I'd like to use two different spring profiles `proda` and `prodb` using Spring Boot 2.0.0 (setting the profile in the `application.properties`).

> In Spring Boot, you can also set the active profile in application.properties, as shown in the following example:
>
> `spring.profiles.active=production`

[Source: 74.6](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles)

---

For now I'm only trying to get `proda` to work. I've got three different property files:

`application-proda.yml`

```yaml
database:
  conn:
    blablabla: blablaqwer
```

and

`application-prodb.yml`

```yaml
database:
  conn:
    blablabla: albalbrewq
```

and also

`application.properties`

```
spring.profiles.active=proda
```

---

When running the application in the IDE, or packaging it as `jar` with maven, everything works as expected (active profiles `[proda]` are set, `application-proda.yml` is loaded). Calling this in (for example a `@PostConstruct` of) some class:

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
```

will result in

```
[proda]
```

but when buildung as `war` with maven, and deploying it to a Tomcat server, the same code will result in

```
[]
```

and `application-proda.yml` is not loaded. That means the application didn't read the `application.properties` and therefore didn't load the active profile `proda` for some reason.

But the finished `war` has all the needed files under `WEB-INF\classes\`.

[image: application.war/WEB-INF/classes/]

---

I've seen some solutions where you can set `-Dspring.profiles.active=proda` as a command line parameter, or set the active profiles in the `web.xml`, but this is not what I need, as I don't have a `web.xml` and I'd like to use the Spring Boot feature and declare the profiles in the `application.properties`. It should work just like in the IDE or packaged as a `jar` with maven.

Comment: IMO you need to set somewhere your custom profile because Spring Boot will try use the default profile if none other is specified. If you do not want to do it by command line or web.xml then you should specify it in code. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267274/spring-boot-programmatically-setting-profiles

Comment: How did you "build a war with maven" (on a jar project)?

Comment: @xerx593 I just used `<packaging>war</packaging>` in the pom.xml