# Spring boot customize external configuration loading sequence

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring boot provides solid configuration support and it has an ability to customize the external configuration loading sequence by controlling the spring profiles, explicitly by specifying loading sequence in system property `spring.config.location`

However I want to not override my application launchers everytime in dev/prod. I want to be able to have fixed loading sequence based on my requirement.

For example

```
config/
├── common.yml
├── env-common.yml
├── env-${dc}.yml
├── deployment-${deployment}-common.yml
├── deployment-${deployment}-${dc}.yml
├── foo-${foo}-common.yml
├── foo-${foo}-${dc}.yml
├── bar-${bar}-common.yml
├── bar-${bar}-${dc}.yml
```

I can achieve this loading sequence by controlling spring profiles, but is there a way I can hardcode this loading sequence inside my app ?

Comment: Do you mean specifically, setting the "spring.config.location" in Java rather than having it as part of the java command line?

Comment: I was wondering if there is hookpoint to customize this. Setting the system property in Java might be too late.

Comment: I believe you can set the property in Java right before running the Spring Application. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267274/spring-boot-programmatically-setting-profiles You would have to manually substitute those properties though, as far as I know.

Comment: I do not want to repeat this in each entry point main. I would love to see if there is a way to customize it in spring way