# Spring boot load profile from external file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would like to read my profile from an external resource. I have 2 environments one for prod and one for dev. I want my dev env to always load with the dev profile without the need to change the property in the application.properties since it will change in git too if someone pushes this change.

I want each machine to load the profile from external file thus eliminating the need to change application.properties each time someone changes it.

I created a file called profile.properties which is not visible by git and added this line:

```
spring.profiles.active=test
```

Then I annotated my class with @PropertySource("classpath:profile.properties") but when I run it I get that the profile is set to default.

I saw the answer here [spring-boot-profiles-with-external-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267274/spring-boot-programmatically-setting-profiles) but still I am not sure how I can read the profile "dev" (as mentioned there) from an external resource.

Comment: You can specify the `spring.profiles.active` property in the command-line, or in an environment variable. Both are external to the application, but not in a property file. Why is command-line or environment variable not adequate?

Comment: Why don't you pass the profile via environment variable or VM argument?

Comment: I saw the option in the IDE itself and I worked with it but if I change IDE I won't have it. When you say environment variable you mean in the control panel -> system properties dialog?

Comment: 54.5 Set the active Spring profiles: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html; Just pass in VM args or ENV

Comment: I added my profile to the environment variables but for some reason it returns null

Comment: 1. I wouldn't set the env variable system-wide on my dev machine - what if you develop another app and you need another profile? 2. Try checking with new terminal window. On windows, new env variables are not loaded into running processes (and child processes inherit them from their parents)

Comment: I was able to load the profile with env variable within the IDE which is intellij. I am thinking what will happen if I switch to eclipse and forget to add this env variable?